# Numerical integration Legendre Polynomials MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

The Legendre polynomials are implemented in MATLAB as vectors, where you also get all the associated Legendre polynomials evaluated at a particular point x. Thus, I don't know how I can use these functions inside an integral. My question is:

How can I evaluate the (NUMERICALLY CALCUALTED(!)) integral from -1 to 1 over the n-th Legendre polynomial in Matlab?

EDIT: As I received an answer that is really not what I want: I want to use the implementation of the Legendre polynomials in MATLAB cause other suggestions may be highly unstable.

Comment: Matlab functions for numerical integration are `trapz` and `cumtrapz`.

Comment: @thewaywewalk yes, but I don't understand how I make him integrating over the Legendre polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n=3 % degree of Legendre polynomial
step=0.1 % integration step
trapz(legendre(n,-1:step:1)')*step
```

this should do what you want

Answer (score 1):

As @thewaywewalk mentionned, you can use trapz to numerically integrate.

Legendre polynomials of degree n are defined as:

[image]

Therefore you can define them in Matlab like so:

```
sym x % You probably have to define x as being symbolic since you integrate as a function of x.
x = -1:0.1:1;

n = 1; Change according to the degree of the polynomial.

F = (x.^2)-1).^n;

Pol_n = (1./((2.^n).*factorial(n))).*diff(F,x,n) % n is the degree of the polynomial
```

Then using trapz :

```
Output = trapz(x,Pol_n)
```

That should get you going.

Comment: no, I would like to use them, the way they are implemented in MATLAB, as this direct definitions is highly unstable ( numerically). See here http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/legendre.html