# How to perform array-based quadrature in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, integral, numerical-integration, numerical-analysis

## Introduction

Consider the following two arrays:

```
N = 100;  % for example

x(1:N) = [real values in ascending order];
y(1:N) = foo(x);
```

**I want to compute the integral of `y` with respect to `x`.**

Let's assume that `y` is not in general defined via a function of `x` (e.g. `foo`). If that were the case, it would be simple to use `quad`, which would make a number of function calls to `foo`. I explicitly want to avoid function-based quadrature because in my situation, I have only `x` and `y`, and there is no handy function (like `foo`) to evaluate.

Note that I would also assume that `foo` is a well-behaved function: continuous and differentiable throughout the domain `[min(x), max(x)]`. Examples of `foo(x)` include `sin(x)`, `exp(x)`, `sqrt` (if `min(x)>0`), `x^2`, and so on. Of course, these example functions may be easily integrated analytically, but we don't learn anything from that. :-)

### Lower Accuracy Solution via `trapz`

I can perform array-based quadrature via the trapezoid method via `trapz`:

```
result = trapz( x, y );
```

### Question

I know that there are a number of ways to approximate this integral with higher accuracy than the `trapz` approach, such as using [Simpson's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_rule). Another way might be to integrate the interpolating Legendre polynomial or spline. I imagine there are other clever ways, as well.

**What is a better way to approximate this integral using MATLAB *besides* `trapz`, and how does it compare with `trapz` in terms of typical accuracy/performance?**

Note: Since at least R2014b, `quad` was marked for deprecation in favor of `integral`. It may be helpful to others to specify the version of MATLAB for which an answer works.

Comment: Not sure your exact question can be answered. I'd say that it's overly broad. This will largely depend on the smoothness and density of your discrete data. Just like with ODE integration, there is no single best quadrature or interpolation scheme. In most cases, `integral` with `interp1` will work fine.

Comment: @horchler: Agreed. I meant to address this by asking for *typical* accuracy/performance. I assumed a comparison would be something like "1st order accurate, assuming a well-behaved function and a uniform grid" — even though the grid is not necessarily uniform and the function is not necessarily well-behaved. This serves as a baseline for comparing different methods. While there isn't a single best scheme for every situation, there are schemes that perform better than others in terms of accuracy (e.g. Runge-Kutta) or speed (Euler method). This comparison is a major part of why I asked.

Comment: The problem with that is that you're veering into mathematics or computational science rather than programming and risk being off-topic for this site. It would be better if you provided specific examples of a "well-behaved function and a uniform grid".

Comment: @horchler: I agree about it being better for those sites. (My bad!) I had asked it because this site has the `matlab` tag. Is there an easy, automated way to move this question to one of those sites?

Comment: Perhaps this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974427/numerical-integration-legendre-polynomials-matlab?rq=1. If so, however, I'm not sure about how it compares to other methods.

Comment: Even if you don't have an analytical form of `foo`, you still have its numerical evaluations, don't you? That's all matlab needs. You can just make a function handle accordingly. If you already have a quadrature, (to my knowledge, despite of its historical meanings, "quadrature" means division of the integrant, not performing the integration itself), you are naturally using to functions like `trapz`, whether it is coded by you or available in base matlab.

Comment: [`integral()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) and [`quadqk()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html) perform integration with adaptive quadratures and are used when you don't have your integrand specified. If you can't evaluate the function as the matlab scripts require, you cannot use those methods. That applies to any adaptive quadrature you develop yourself too. If you already have a quadrature, and you are not happy with its accuracy, you need to either have finer divisions, or develop something else.

Comment: You don't need to call the quadrature functions `quad`, `quadl` etc unless you need to test how they behave with the function you are trying to integrate. If you are using this for research purpose, you have to have other means to confirm the validity of the results when you use what is essentially a black-box proprietary software. As long as you can verify the results, you shouldn't have to talk about how you computed the integrals. And thus you shouldn't need to worry about how matlab handles adaptive quadrature.

Comment: Finally, as @horchler points out, from how you describe adaptive quadrature, the issue you have seems to be a math one (computational math is math and not computer science nor programming). We can have some exchanges in the comment section and you can take advantage of the attention that SO receives which other stackexchange sites don't. But ultimately, you need to clarify the math yourself and nail the question down to a programming one.